# Pronunciation Software

Tags: .net

I am trying to build a software in .NET that will take a said word as input and will compare it's pronunciation against the correct pronunciation.Till now i was able to make a simple voice recorder that will record the word but how do i compare it against the correct pronunciation?Are there any javascript that will provide this functionality?If yes then i would like to have the link or any other method that i could implement to forward in this project.

This software is a part of my final year project.Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: If there is any javascript, it will be a jquery plugin.

Comment: @leppie could you provide me a link?

Comment: Audio comparison is a very tricky topic. This question might provide some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756214/how-to-compare-two-audio-data